# Camera Clipping when entering the Camera View

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

When rendering my scene i get the following issue. (Blender 3.3.1 with cycles)

Outside of the camera the view of a large ocean is as shown below
[image]

However if I press Num0 to get inside the camera view i get the following clipping
[image]

The view settings on the sidebar as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone know where this clipping is coming from the settings?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2):

Select your camera, go to camera properties and set the clip start and end (which is independent from View settings).

[image]